# Difference between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, date-arithmetic

I have a table that has the following data

```
fromDate | toDate
20JAN11  | 29DEC30
```

Both dates are for the 21st Century (i.e. 2011 and 2030) but only the last two characters are stored.

Why is the following statement (when run from within a PL/SQL module) against the above data always returns a positive value

```
dateDifference := (fromDate - toDate)
```

If i run the following statement from sqlplus i get the correct  negative value which is correct.

```
select to_date('20JAN11','DDMONYY')-to_Date('29DEC30','DDMONYY') from dual;
```

I remember reading somewhere that Oracle would sometimes use the wrong century but i dont quite remember the exact scenario where that would happen.

Comment: What's your question?  If you're concerned then insert/inject "20" into the string, but I'd strongly recommend changing the data type to DATE.

Comment: Im sure there was a question in there somewhere (see 3rd sentence :-)). 
The data type is DATE for the two columns. The problem i have is that the statement is returning a positive value if i run it from within the pl/sql block. 
I know it will work if i prefix the date with "20" but im trying to find out why it is happening. The plsql code does not use any formatting to get the difference so the question i had was what is causing it to do that.  :)

Comment: What happens to your date if you do an
 `alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd mmm yyyy';`
and select fromDate and toDate?

Comment: You may need to check that the year value stored in the table really is what you expect; with your default format mask you can't tell which century it is. I'd guess your `20JAN11` date is 2111 instead of 2011.

Comment: If your columns are defined as DATEs, it is not possible that only the last two digits of the year are being stored.  An Oracle date always contains a month, day, and full year along with a time to the second.  Your default NLS_DATE_FORMAT may cause the default display of that date to include only the last two digits of the year and to not include the time (hence Rene's suggestion).  But echoing Alex, I'm going to wager that the data in the table isn't actually what you think it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming those columns are of `DATE` datatype, which seems to be the case:  Oracle always stores `DATE` values in an internal format which includes the full year.  The fact that you are seeing only a 2-digit year has to do with the date format used to convert the date to a string for display.  So most likely the stored century values are not what you think they are.

Try selecting the dates with an explicit format to see what you really have stored:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( fromDate, 'DD-MON-YYYY' ), TO_CHAR( toDate, 'DD-MON-YYYY' )
```

Comment: You are right. I checked the data and it is stored in the 19th Century as  20-JAN-2011 and 29-DEC-1930

Comment: It looks like the problem is with the source data. The data that was uploaded was using the wrong century. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work for me either way on my 10g database:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> 
SQL> DECLARE
  2    d1   DATE := to_date('20JAN11','DDMONRR');
  3    d2   DATE := to_date('29DEC30','DDMONRR');
  4    diff INTEGER;
  5  BEGIN
  6    diff := d1 - d2;
  7    dbms_output.put_line(diff);
  8  END;
  9  /

-7283

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL>
```

EDIT: works for YY instead of RR year format as well.

EDIT2: Something like this, you mean?

```
SQL> create table t (d1 date, d2 date);

Table created

SQL> insert into t values (to_date('20JAN11','DDMONYY'), to_date('29DEC30','DDMONYY'));

1 row inserted

SQL> commit;

Commit complete

SQL> 
SQL> DECLARE
  2    R    t%ROWTYPE;
  3    diff INTEGER;
  4  BEGIN
  5    SELECT d1, d2
  6      INTO R
  7      FROM t;
  8    diff := R.d1 - R.d2;
  9    dbms_output.put_line(diff);
 10  END;
 11  /

-7283

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL>
```

As @Alex states, you may want to verify your data.

Comment: Thats different because i am reading the data from a table and doing the subtraction without using any formating wheras you are using DDMONRR. 

I read the data into a cursor and just use the cursor values e.g. cursorname.fromDate-cursorName.toDate

Comment: It looks like the problem is with the source data. The data that was uploaded was using the wrong century. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

works without formatting as well

```
CREATE  TABLE DATETEST(FROMDATE DATE, TODATE DATE);
insert into DATETEST (fromdate,todate) values (to_date('20Jan11','ddMonrr'),to_date('29DEC30','ddMonrr'));

SELECT TO_CHAR(FROMDATE,'ddMonrrrr hh24:mi:ss') FROMDATE, 
       TO_CHAR(TODATE,'ddMonrrrr hh24:mi:ss') TODATE
  from datetest ;

  /*
FROMDATE           TODATE             
------------------ ------------------ 
20Jan2011 00:00:00 29Dec2030 00:00:00 
*/




set serveroutput on
DECLARE 
 l_FROMDATE DATETEST.FROMDATE%type ;
 L_TODATE DATETEST.TODATE%TYPE;
 dateDifference  number;
BEGIN
--notice -- no formatting just putting them into a variable for test
SELECT FROMDATE, TODATE 
    INTO L_FROMDATE, L_TODATE
from datetest;


DATEDIFFERENCE  := L_FROMDATE - L_TODATE ;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DATEDIFFERENCE  = ' || DATEDIFFERENCE  );
end ;

--DATEDIFFERENCE  = -7283

SELECT FROMDATE-TODATE
from datetest ;

/* --still not formatting
FROMDATE-TODATE        
---------------------- 
-7283  
*/


SELECT (FROMDATE - TODATE) DATEDIFF, 
       TO_CHAR(FROMDATE,'ddMonrrrr') FROMDATE, 
       to_char(todate,'ddMonrrrr') todate 
from (
        SELECT TO_DATE('20JAN11','DDMONYY') FROMDATE, 
               TO_DATE('29DEC30','DDMONYY') TODATE 
          FROM DUAL) 
;
/*

DATEDIFF               FROMDATE  TODATE    
---------------------- --------- --------- 
-7283                  20Jan2011 29Dec2030 

*/
```

try running the first query on your table:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(FROMDATE,'ddMonrrrr hh24:mi:ss') FROMDATE, 
       TO_CHAR(TODATE,'ddMonrrrr hh24:mi:ss') TODATE
  from datetest ;
```

see if the years are what you actually expect.

(Edit: changed to use two digit years)

Comment: Check the values you inserted in the table. Your data has the dates 20Jan2011 and 29Dec2030. The data in the table i am using is 20Jan11 and 29Dec30. (i.e. the year is 2 characters)

Comment: @ziggy, changed to use two digit years, same results.